# Measure of non-compactness

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory, compactness, compact-operators

Can someone give me some simple examples of measure of non-compactness of sets in Banach spaces or metric spaces, which are easy to understand.

Comment: When you say "measure of non-compactness", do you mean "how far the set is from being compact"?

Comment: yes.. but it can be for particular types of measure of non-compactness. e.g. ball-measure or Kurawski's measure etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Sets:** For a bounded subset $A$ of a Banach space $X$ you can define
$$  \gamma(A) = \inf\{\epsilon > 0 : A \text{ can be covered by finitely many balls of radius } \epsilon \}$$
and you have $\gamma(A) = 0$ iff $A$ is relatively compact.

**Operators:** 
Let $B(X)$ the Banach space of bounded operators acting on $X$ and $T\in B(X)$.

- Using the above definition for sets you can set $\gamma(T) = \gamma(T B_X)$ where $B_X$ is the unit ball in $X$.
- Define
  $$\|T\|_\mu = \inf \{\|T|_M\|:M\subset X \text{ subspace of finte codimension}\}.$$ Then $\|\cdot\|_\mu$ is a seminorm on $B(X)$ and an algebra seminorm and defines an algebra norm on the Calkin algebra $B(X)/K(X)$.

Both examples are measures of non-compactness, i.e. $\|T\|_\mu = 0$ and $\gamma(T)=0$ iff $T$ is compact.